# Azure DevOps Edit Default Topic Branch Name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server

How can i set the default pattern of new Pull Request Branch Name
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot set the field `Topic branch name` default name. The default is `commitID or branch name-on-target branch name` and we could change it manually.

Note: If we change the `Target branch` value, the field `Topic branch name` will come back.

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.